# Incomprehensible case expression with macros

Tags: verilog

In preparation for an exam, I want to go over some Verilog Code and I'm using https://www.jdoodle.com/ as a compiler. But for some reason the cases throw errors.

```
jdoodle.v:20: syntax error
jdoodle.v:20: error: Incomprehensible case expression.
jdoodle.v:21: syntax error
jdoodle.v:21: error: Incomprehensible case expression.
jdoodle.v:22: syntax error
jdoodle.v:22: error: Incomprehensible case expression.
jdoodle.v:23: syntax error
jdoodle.v:23: error: Incomprehensible case expression.
jdoodle.v:24: syntax error
jdoodle.v:24: error: Incomprehensible case expression.
```

```
module ALU (
    input wire [2:0]OPCODE,
    input wire [31:0]A,
                     B,
    output reg [31:0]RESULT
);

`define ADD 0;
`define SUB 1;
`define MULT 2;
`define DIV 3;
`define MOD 4;

function [31:0] calculate (
    input [31:0] A,
    input [31:0] B,
    input [2:0] OPCODE
); 
    case (OPCODE)
        `ADD: calculate = A + B;
        `SUB: calculate = A - B;
        `MULT: calculate = A * B;
        `DIV: calculate = A / B;
        `MOD: calculate = A % B;
    endcase
endfunction

always @(A or B or OPCODE)
    RESULT = calculate(A, B, OPCODE);

endmodule
```

Would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end your defines.

You are defining ADD as `0;`
Thus your code becomes:

```
case (OPCODE)
    0; : calculate = A + B;
    1; : calculate = A - B;
    2; : calculate = A * B;
    3; : calculate = A / B;
    4; : calculate = A % B;
endcase
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Oh jeez, no clue why I put them there.

Comment: The reason why I spot them so quickly is that in my 30 years of coding, I have made every error possible. And yes, yours is one of them.